# Calculate probability of interval given probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P$ be a probability measure over $\mathbb{R}$:

$$P((x,\infty)) =
\begin{cases}
\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-2}, & x\gt0 \\
1 , & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Calculate $P((2,3])$.

I think I need to find a clever way to represent $(2,3]$ as union of open intervals but I'm not able to find a way to do so without getting an interval of the form $(-\infty,y)$.

Please any help or direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$(2,3]\cup(3,\infty)=(2,\infty)$

The set on LHS are disjoint and a probability measure is additive.